# Call Firebase cloud function via GET and return parameters

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created this cloud function:

```
exports.returnUid = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
    const uid = req.query.uid
    res.send(uid)
});
```

When I call `https://<project>.cloudfunctions.net/returnUid?uid=123abc`, it returns an empty response, and not the "uid" parameter as it should.

Comment: It should work normally. Any error in the log on the Firebase console? Which version of Node.js you are using (look at the `engines` field in the `package.json` file that is in the `functions`directory)?

Comment: No errors, runs successfully: `functions: Finished "getUid" in ~1s
`. Running Node version 8

Comment: Maybe because I'm running the function via firebase serve using google cloud shell?

Comment: When I deploy the function, it works. Must be an issue with Google Cloud Shell.

Comment: Apparently. I had tried it after deployment and it worked.

Comment: Does it work for you if you serve it locally using `firebase serve`? Because when I deploy it, it does. But not when being served locally.

Comment: If you find a problem with the local emulator, please file an issue on the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that when using `firebase --serve`, the function won't acept parameters. But when I deplpoy it, it does.