# How can I get the params from a "get request" in a firebase function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I know the request param in a firebase https.onRequest corresponds to a Express response.

I want to run the cloud function using this format (local testing):

```
http://localhost:5000/test-2c6e8/us-central1/coins?userid=1
```

So, now from the cloud function I just want to get the userId param. The test function I have written is:

```
exports.coins = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
{
    var db = admin.firestore();
    response.json({query: JSON.stringify(request.query),
                   params: JSON.stringify(request.params),
                   body: JSON.stringify(request.body)});
    response.end();
});
```

and this is the output I get:

```
query   "{}"
params  "{\"0\":\"\"}"
body    "{}"
```

I have tried multiple things without any luck. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your Cloud Function should run correctly if you deploy it. You may encounter problem depending on the way you test it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289923/call-firebase-cloud-function-via-get-and-return-parameters

Comment: If you find a problem with the local emulator, please file an issue on the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is `req.query.name_of_the_parameter`; for the long answer, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744697/parameters-in-firebase-cloud-functions-https).

Comment: A life saver, thank you !