# Firestore Cloud Function - How to read params from url

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to extract the params from http url in firestore cloud function,
HTTP URL

```
 https://us-central-xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/somefunction?name=ABC&age=80
```

Firestore Cloud function

```
export const somefunction = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  var name = // need to extract name from request
  var age = // similarly need to extract age from request
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `request` object to access the query parameters similar to what you do in [Express Js](https://expressjs.com/)

```
export const somefunction = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  var name = request.query.name
  var age = request.query.age
}
```

If the request was from a **POST** request then you can use `request.body.*` for accessing values.

Comment: Are you getting null?

Comment: How do you test it? After deployment or with the local emulator? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289923/call-firebase-cloud-function-via-get-and-return-parameters

Comment: Seems like its a problem with the local emulator. Are you using node 8? This will work in production that I am sure. I unfortunately can't help with what's going on in the local machine. Sorry.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any solution yet?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305935/cannot-get-req-path-and-req-query-abc-with-firebase-functions

Comment: I have updated the firebase-tools' version to 4.0.0. I'm using node 8 and this helped me resolve the issue, temporarily, for developement. 
https://howtofirebase.com/cloud-functions-migrating-to-node-8-9640731a8acc

Comment: This is the correct solution and should be marked as the accepted answer. Firebase http functions work exactly the same way as ExpressJS endpoints and the Req and Res objects are likewise the same API's.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue where I cannot get `req.url` and `req.query.abc` as asked in [Cannot get req.path and req.query.abc with firebase functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56305935/cannot-get-req-path-and-req-query-abc-with-firebase-functions)

As mentioned in the comments of [Call Firebase cloud function via GET and return parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289923/call-firebase-cloud-function-via-get-and-return-parameters) this is happening only on development.

After searching for a long time I came across this article https://howtofirebase.com/cloud-functions-migrating-to-node-8-9640731a8acc where it said `firebase-tools` have to be of 4.0.0 version. I've updated my `firebase-tools` to 4.0.0 and I can get the query parameters normally