# Cannot get req.path and req.query.abc with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, express, request, google-cloud-functions, query-string

I'm trying to get the request query params and url in `firebase functions`. 
Here is the code I'm using

`firebase.json`

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "build",
        "rewrites": [{
            "source": "/getCoins",
            "function": "getCoins"
        }]
    }
}
```

Using `"firebase-functions": "^2.3.1"` in `package.json`

`functions/index.js`

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.getCoins = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query); // [object Object]
    console.log(req.query.repeat); // empty
    console.log(req.url); // '/'
    console.log(req.originalUrl); // '/'
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Started the firebase functions in my windows command prompt using `firebase serve --only functions`. As it starts serving data from `http://localhost:5000`, I'm trying to request `http://localhost:5000/coins-app/us-central1/getCoins?repeat=4`

I'm not getting any error in the command prompt, but could only see the commented lines from the above `functions/index.js` code.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `firebase serve` and request to http://localhost:5000/getCoins?repeat=4 .

`functions.https.onRequest()` can't accept query string parameter directly.

Comment: Thanks! This can be contributing as well, but I'm able to get it working by upgrading firebase-tools to 4.0.0

Comment: Did you run `firebase serve`? Not `firebase serve --only functions`.